# XML not valid in Arduino project

Tags: xml, arduino

I am doing a project with arduino and I have to send an XML file to a web browser. This file is made by arduino and sent by itself. The problem is that the file is not correctly recognaized by the AJAX code in the web (or even the browser if I request the file on my own) so it seems that the file is not correctly constructed, but I don't know why. This is how it looks like:

```
  <?xml version = '1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<inputs>
   <dato>
    23
   </dato>
</inputs>
```

This is a simple version for testing the XML file. I have reduced the code as much as I could. As you can see it appears to be a typical XML file, but it doesn't work!! Any idea??

Thanks!!

Comment: I forget to say that when I change the AJAX code and write responseText in spite of responseXML it detects the code, but as a text file so it means that the file is correctly sent.

Comment: The XML looks good to me although the blanks in front of the first line look a little strange. But what about code pages, newline characters etc? I suggest you take a look at the actual bytes being sent and see if anything is weird.

Comment: How can I take a look at the bytes being sent?